# "Route [demandas.estado.update] not defined" pero existe en el controlador resource, Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]EstadoController

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $estado=Estado::findOrFail($id);
        return view("demandas.estado.edit",["estado"=>Estado::findOrFail($id)]);
    }


    public function update(EstadoFormRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $estado=Estado::findOrFail($id);
        $estado->nombreEstado = $request->get('nombreEstado');
        $estado->update();
        return Redirect::to('demandas/estado');
    }
```

modelo

```
protected $table = 'estados';
```

ruta:

```
Route::resource('demandas/estado','EstadoController');
```

Modelo de formulario en edit.blade.php:

```
{!!Form::model($juzgado,['method'=>'PATCH','route'=>['demandas.juzgado.update',$juzgado->idJuzgado],'files'=>'true'])!!}
```

me sale la excepción

> Route [demandas.estado.update] not defined. 
>   resources\views\demandas\estado\edit.blade.php

No entiendo cómo la ruta no está definida  ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¡Gracias!

Comment: ¿qué aparece en `php artisan route:list`? Al parecer no es el mismo formulario? en ese veo que la ruta es `demandas.juzgado.update`

Comment: hola Shaz acabe de adjuntar la imagen del route:list  pero si me aparece la ruta

Comment: Jhonatan, podias decirme, que cambio tengo que hacer, porque me sale el mismo problema y no puedo solucionarlo willy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te fijas en el resultado de `php artisan route:list`, el nombre de la ruta es `estado.update`  y no `demandas.estado.update`, no estoy seguro pero tal vez sea por el uso de la barra oblicua que Laravel solo tome la última palabra para definir el nombre de la ruta.

Prueba `php artisan route:clear` en caso que el nombre no aparezca "correctamente" por asunto de caché.

Comment: parcero muchas gracias, me sirvio su explicacion , Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema y encontré lo siguiente, al utilizar el código:

```
Route::resource('demandas/estado','EstadoController');
```

Te crea los nombres de rutas del tipo: **estado.index | estado.show**, etc. como lo puedes ver en tu screenshot del listado de rutas.

Por lo que al usar la ruta '**demandas.juzgado.update**' en el form de tu view no la encuentra:

```
{!!Form::model($juzgado,['method'=>'PATCH','route'=>['demandas.juzgado.update',$juzgado->idJuzgado],'files'=>'true'])!!}
```

Para convertir los nombres de las rutas al tipo: **demandas.estado.index | demandas.estado.show**, etc. puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
Route::resource('demandas/estado','EstadoController', ['as' => 'demandas']);
```

Después puedes usar el comando `php artisan route:list` para corroborar los cambios.